# laravel replicate() method and computed database column

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to copy a row using by replicate() method:

```
$doc = Doc::find(64618);
$newdoc = $doc->replicate();
$newdoc->Price= 9999; 
$newdoc->save();
```

but this table contains several computed columns and I get an error that the data fields can not be updated.
How can I exclude these fields when using replicate()?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the columns that you want to excludes

```
$doc = Doc::find(64618);
$newdoc = $doc->replicate(['column1', 'column2']);
$newdoc->Price= 9999; 
$newdoc->save();
```

Here is the source you will find out if u deep dive into the core.

```
/**
     * Clone the model into a new, non-existing instance.
     *
     * @param  array|null  $except
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
     */
    public function replicate(array $except = null)
    {
        $defaults = [
            $this->getKeyName(),
            $this->getCreatedAtColumn(),
            $this->getUpdatedAtColumn(),
        ];

        $except = $except ? array_unique(array_merge($except, $defaults)) : $defaults;

        $attributes = Arr::except($this->attributes, $except);

        $instance = new static;

        $instance->setRawAttributes($attributes);

        return $instance->setRelations($this->relations);
    }
```

Comment: Hello, how would you do this dynamically like you don't know the  generated columns you are just trying to replicate model X?